# How to get selected values from database

Tags: android, sqlite

I want  only selected values form database depends upon i and j?

```
public Cursor getAll() {
         int i=2;j=1;  
           return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                        "SELECT _id,note,answer From Notes where _id=? AND note=?",new String[]{i+""},new String[]{j+""}));
        }
```

Comment: Accept some answers especially the one below if its now working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
public Cursor getAll() {
   int i=2;
   return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id,note,answer From Notes where _id=? ",new String[]{i+""}));
}
```

For multiple arguments...

```
public Cursor getAll() {
     int i=2;j=1;  
       return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                    "SELECT _id,note,answer From Notes where _id=? AND note=?",new String[]{i+"", j+""}));
    }
```

Comment: @Puneet Joshi, dude accept the answer otherwise you will loose the confidence of the experts and they will hesitate to answer your questions

Comment: @Puneet Joshi good. similarly dear If the answers on your other questions have solved your problem, accept them too. The reason is stated above.